# Javascript for getting windows size, but at failure, run standard values

Tags: javascript

I have made with vb.net a asp.net website. I needed to  get the windows size and successfully included the following JavaScript together  with the WindowSize ashx. This gives me nicely the widow size. It seems that sometimes it does not completely work (on somebodies IPhone). I really do not know anything about Java but it gives the failure popup when it can not get the width and height.

What I would like is to still get the message but also that the script still continues with a given value for width and for height (Width= 768, Height= 854).

For somebody who knows JavaScript this is probably very simple but for me... The problem is also I can not really test it while I do not have the Phone myself. All my browsers get recognized....

Please, who wants to adapt this code for me so that this is included??

Thanks in advance.

```js
function SetWidthHeight() {
    var height = $(window).height();
    var width = $(window).width();
    $.ajax({
        url: "windowSize.ashx",
        data: {
            'Height': height,
            'Width': width
        },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function (data) {
        if (data.isFirst) {
            window.location.reload();
        };
    }).fail(function (xhr) {
        alert("Problem to retrieve the correct browser size.");
    });

}
```

Comment: Java has NOTHING to do with JavaScript

Comment: What is not working on the iphone exactly? Does it make the call? Is it returning the wrong size?

Comment: sorry about the java. for me that is all like magic...  It is returning the message "Problem to retrieve the correct browser size" on that iPhone. (i do not know the version). I know on another Iphone it is working....Anyway, to be sure it Always displays something, I first would like to solve it with assuming a width and height.....

Comment: So what is the reason for the failure? What did the server do that causes the error? Did you look at the reason for the failure? jQuery gives messages in the arguments of the fail method.

Comment: Should I be able to find the error in the server logs? This might be searching for a needle in a haystack.... I adjusted the code according the below scripts and I am waiting for feedback of this user with the Iphone..

Comment: alert the error message on the client and see if that gives any hints: `.fail(function (xhr, status, message){ alert(status + "\n" + message); });`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can set default values like this -

```
function SetWidthHeight() {
var height = $(window).height();;
var width = $(window).width();
height = (height) ? height : 854;
width = (width) ? width : 768;
$.ajax({
    url: "windowSize.ashx",
    data: {
        'Height': height,
        'Width': width
    },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json"
}).done(function (data) {
    if (data.isFirst) {
        window.location.reload();
    };
}).fail(function (xhr) {
    alert("Problem to retrieve the correct browser size.");
});

}
```

Comment: I did this and it seem to work. Thanks. Now, they get at least something in their screen although the screen is not nicely build to the real screensize.. But, that was my goal for now...

Answer (score -1):

First, you set default values and after you try to find out the parameters.

```
...

var height = 854;
var width = 768;
try {
  height = $(window).height();
  width = $(window).width();
} catch(Exception e) { }

$.ajax({ ...
```

PS: it is just javascript.

Comment: This might not work as jQuery rarely throws exceptions.

Comment: You are probably right. I think your code works better. :)

Comment: Looks logical. It starts Always with a value but will it still do it's reload function? While I understood it needs to do a reload to get the correct width and height (the script passes first my vb.script also without data and only the second time it does something)

Comment: In reaction to my above comment. it runs the script like Always. First pass he does not run the complete script due to the ( If Not (IsNothing(Session("BrowserWidth"))) Then). I was afraid it would now contain data the first time but this did not happen. So that is ok.

Comment: I did not try it while I ran the other solution and that worked. Trying to understand these codes, I assume they do about the same...